# MySQL select help inner join?

Tags: mysql

I am writing a php script that displays the following columns project_name, customer_name, fName, lName, activeproject. This is part of website for my senior project i really need help.

My tables are setup as follows:
**Project**
project_id, project_name, description, custid, projectmgrempid, activeproject

**Employee**
staff_id, fName, lName

**Customer**
cust_id, cust_fname

here is what i have that gives me an error

```
select t1.project_id, t1.project_name, t1.description, 
t1.custid, t1.projectmgrempid, t1.activeproject, t2.fName, t2.lName, t3.customer_id,    t3.customer_name
from projects t1
inner join employee t2 on t1.projectmgrempid = t2.staff_id
where t1.activeproject = `open`
inner join customer t3 on t1.custid = t3.customer_id;
```

> The error is #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'inner join customer t3 on t1.custid =
>   t3.customer_id LIMIT 0, 30' at line 6

Comment: is the table name projects or project?

Comment: You can't put a JOIN after a WHERE.  It goes SELECT... FROM... JOIN... WHERE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your where clause should appear after your join clause.

```
select t1.project_id, t1.project_name, t1.description, 
t1.custid, t1.projectmgrempid, t1.activeproject, 
t2.fName, t2.lName, t3.customer_id,    t3.customer_name
from projects t1
inner join employee t2 on t1.projectmgrempid = t2.staff_id
inner join customer t3 on t1.custid = t3.customer_id
where t1.activeproject = 'open';
```

Comment: and the string `'open'` in the where clause should be in single quotes not backticks.

Comment: oops! Corrected. Thanks anyway.